# Is "standard basis" countable or not? I guess not and need a double check

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

This question comes from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3282322/673047).

> This figure is trying to illustrate 4 spaces defined by 4 different
>   set of standard basis.

In mathematics, the [standard basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis) (also called natural basis) for a Euclidean space is the **`set`** of unit vectors pointing in the direction of the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system.

Is "standard basis" here countable or not? I guess not and need a double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very quote in the question answers the question:

> ...4 spaces defined by 4 different set of standard basis.

or more correctly in my view:

> ...4 spaces defined by 4 different sets of standard bases.

"Basis" is countable, the plural is "bases" as shown by [this disctionary.comn link](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/basis) winch gives as sense 5:

> Mathematics. a set of linearly independent elements of a given vector space having the property that every element of the space can be written as a linear combination of the elements of the set.

[This Macmillan entry](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/basis) also shows it as countable, as does [this merriam-webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/basis)

Now while it is true that for any one space there is only one **standard** basis, there are different bases for different spaces. In any case "basis" is countable, even if in a particular use only one standard basis exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in the phrasing:

### 1. A standard basis is already a set

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis):

> The standard basis (also called natural basis) for a Euclidean space is the set of unit vectors pointing in the direction of the axes of a Cartesian coordinate system.

Therefore, "sets of standard basis" would imply multiple groupings of different standard basis. However, the OP is referring to a pair of vectors as a "set of standard basis", which is incorrect because the standard basis is already that set of vectors. Therefore a *more* appropriate phrasing would be:

> 4 different standard bases

Where "bases" is the plural of basis, pronounced like \ˈbā-​ˌsēz\ and not \ˈbā-​səz\

---

That is not to say you cannot have "sets of bases" but that is not what is in the OP's post.

### 2. There is only one Standard Basis in any space

The issue is, only the upper left graph is showing *the* standard basis for the real plan. The rest are just sets that make a orthogonal unit basis of the real plane.

A standard basis is the specifically ordered set of unit vectors e<sub>i</sub>, with 1 in the i<sup>th</sup> coordinate:

> R<sup>2</sup>  (1,0); (0,1)
>
> R<sup>3</sup>  (1,0,0); (0,1,0); (0,0,1)
>
> R<sup>4</sup>  (1,0,0,0); (0,1,0,0); (0,0,1,0);  (0,0,0,1)
>
> etc.

*standard basis* is not appropriate ot refer to those four diagrams because only one of them is **the** standard basis for R<sup>2</sup>. See [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis#Properties).

---

Therefore, the grammatically and mathematically correct way to phrase this statement could be:

> This figure is trying to illustrate 4 spaces defined by 4 different bases.

It could be made more precise by adding the adjective "orthogonal" and "unit" would be appropriate. (Also note that the OP goes on to say that all 4 spaces are the same space, which is correct)